# check if int is equal to another int give or take x

Tags: java, integer

I have sprites drawn onto a location and would like to create an statement which is similar to

```
if(int y == int x (give or take 30)) {
    //do something
}
```

I basically have a sprite drawn at a set location

```
if (y >= 520 - enemyHeight - ySpeed || y + ySpeed <= 310) {
    ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    if (ySpeed > 0) {
        direction = 0;
    }
}
```

and I want to check if that y is within a certain int of another value, slowly increment it towards that value.

Comment: Check if `(y >= (x - 30)) && (y <= (x + 30))`

Comment: The Math.abs approach is perhaps more "intellectual", but there's certainly nothing wrong with the suggestion by @DaveNewton.

Comment: (And if you're going to do a lot of this, write an `equalWithin(a,b,delta)` method.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've taken these into account and it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the difference between your integer and the target value is less than the 'give or take' value - something like this:

```
if (Math.abs(y - x) <= 30)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry to ask, would you happen to know how to increment the y position by an int to gradually move to x, so if y is within 30 of x, move it to x by increments of 5 or so?

Comment: Well, inside the 'if' statement you could then have something like 'if (y > x) y -= 5; else if (y < x) y += 5;' (replacing 5 with whatever speed you want it to move towards x at). However, this will oscillate around x if the difference isn't a multiple of 5 so you might also want to make it stop moving and just set its value to x once it's close enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, exactly what I wanted and nicely laid out!